# What can we say about the set X?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have a certain set $X$ for which is valid: $\forall U\subset X:[ U\neq X ]\rightarrow U\nsim X$. What can we say about $X$? I think we've got to use the axiom of choice here. My first guess would be to say that $X$ is finite, but I'm not sure...

Comment: See [Dedekind infinitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).

Answer (score 1):

If you translate the definition into words, you'll see that it says that $X$ is such that no proper subset of $X$ has the same cardinality as $X$. In other words, this means that if $f\colon X\to X$ is injective, then it is surjective. This is Dedekind's definition for finiteness.

Of course finite sets have this property, but without the axiom of choice (or at least the axiom of choice for countable families of sets) we cannot prove the converse. It is consistent that the axiom of choice fails, and there are infinite sets which are Dedekind-finite.